# Force Exchange 2010 to consolidate transaction logs without Windows Server Backup

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

I perform a VM-level backup on our Exchange 2010 server rather than Windows-level backup, but I've noticed that as a result (since Windows Backup has never run) there are a lot of logs. How can I get Exchange to consolidate these safely without running Windows Backup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't care about the logs, turn on circular logging. If you care about the logs, then use a backup method that is Exchange aware.

Comment: You beat me to the punch...

Answer (score 2):

You have to run an Exchange aware backup that can flush the transaction logs as part of the backup or you have to enable circular logging (which isn't recommended in most scenarios).

Comment: Why is circular logging so bad?

Comment: It limits the recoverability of the mailbox databases. - See here for more info (releative to all versions of Exchange) - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb331951(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: It's not bad, however the usage of it should be done ONLY if you totally understand what and how it will SOLVE your problem.